# What are the screen resolution possibilities when targeting pc/mac

Tags: resolution

I'm coping with a huge problem at the moment, concerning screen resolution. As i'm a college student the only tools i have for developing the game i'm making is open source software and a laptop running windows with a 1366x768 resolution.

I recently found out that it's best to develop your game on a 1920x1080 resolution since it's common.

Now wondering if there is some sort of workaround since i dont have acces to a screen that has that resolution or higher and my sprites will probably blurr when displayed on such resolution.

Comment: Yes, a raster-based sprite which is going to be stretched in order to appear the same size proportionally to the pixel dimensions of the viewport (i.e. 1024x768; 1920x1080 etc) will "blur" or look less good. The solution is to provide multiple versions of all assets. This question, and others I think you posted similar to it may be better served at the http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ I am certain this is a duplicate of something there, so try the search feature before posting.

Comment: Note that normally, games are developed to support a wide range of screen aspects and pixel dimensions, not just a single target. It takes a little time, but dig around for a good design pattern before you fully commit.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Im sort-of lost in what your question is at the moment.  Are you asking for monitor suggestions, veridication on what resolutions to design for, or how to generate a work envirnmonet.   If you can edit your question if a little bit more information on what your question is we can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution of your screen has nothing to do with the size of images you can create.

I can create a 1200x1600 image on a 600x800 screen. It just means I'll have to do some zooming and panning and scrolling to see it at actual size.

UPDATE:

It would help to understand how you plan on accommodating different screens. Assuming you want to make a full-screen game, there are a few scenarios you could consider:

- Design your imagery at a specific size, then stretch-to-fit.

  - Pros: One set of assets. One 'playing field'. If you design them fairly large to begin with, they should render fairly well even when stretched.
  - Cons: You need to account for aspect ratio differences (perhaps letterbox as needed). Shrinking down too far or up too far could produce a reduction in quality that is unsatisfactory.
- Design your imagery at a specific size, but then crop/expand the playing field rather than stretching.

  - Pros: Assets are shown at 'actual size'. There is no aspect ratio issues.
  - Cons: Depending on the design game, this may or may not work.
- Design to specific screen resolutions.

  - Pros: It will look 'perfect' on each screen you design for.
  - Cons: It may require creating several versions of each asset.
- Build the game using vector-based assets.

  - Pros: Vectors can scale up and down without a loss in quality.
  - Cons: Not all platforms/gaming dev platforms support them.

Comment: I dont think you understand what is being asked...

Comment: @user24028 then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: it's not about the image size , it's about the resolution. i honestly think you lack the knowledge to help me out here.

Comment: @user24028 feel free to ask your question elsewhere. If you want an answer here, then you need to actually clarify what you are asking. FYI--image size and resolution are meaningless without context. Give us the context, and we can try and give you a better answer.

Comment: As you know , a screen set on 1980x1080 will display a 200x200 image different from a 1366x768 set screen. The image will probably suffer a lack of quality and proportion changes.

Comment: Thats why my question was , if there is a way to develop for 1980x1080 setting without having a screen that has those dimensions.

Comment: @user24028 I truly am trying to help, but you need to explain things in more details. A 200x200 image in say, a web browser, will always be 200x200 regardless of the screen resolution. No change in quality and proportion. If your game, however, is going to stretch things to fill any screen, then that is an issue. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: And my answer fits your question. In terms of images, you can develop them to any screen resolution you want to. It's just that if your screen resolution is SMALLER than the image size, you'll have to use scrollbars to see it all in PhotoShop, for example.

Comment: yes , it's concerning sprites based on the png format.

Comment: So, for example, if you need to create a background image for your 1980x1080, open photoshop, create a new image at that size, then save it out as a PNG. Will that work for you? Or am I still missing something in understanding the issue?

Comment: Key bit of info I think we need here: Is this a 'full screen' game you are creating? If so, are you planning on stretching everything, or expanding the 'playing field'? I updated my answer with more details that hopefully help.

Comment: @DA01 its one of those confusions like question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31263/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-resolution-property-of-images-when-creating-editing/31291#31291 where te asker does have a misunderstanding on how things work thus can not accept a valid answer. Anyway having sufficently large assets should work fine for unity. Scaling up is horrible scaling down is often acceptable except in the extreme end. Anyway resolution does not come to play here.